# How to return selection after copying js?

Tags: javascript

Text copy function:

```
function copyToClipboard(str) {
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = str;
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.left = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    const selected =
        document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0
            ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
            : false;
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
    if (selected) {
        document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        document.getSelection().addRange(selected);
    }
};
```

Which is better: scan the entire document and look for an element on which the focus is set, or pass the selector to the function the second parameter to which you want to return the selection and then just set focus there again?